# How to write an UDF in Spark to map indexes to string labels?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark and I have a table that has a specific string format in one of the columns called `predictions`. The format is always of the type - `0=some_probability,1=some_other_probability,2=some_other_probability` .

Here are a few sample records from that table -

```
val table1 = Seq(
("0=0.5,1=0.3,2=0.2"),
("0=0.6,1=0.2,2=0.2"),
("0=0.1,1=0.1,2=0.8")
).toDF("predictions")

table1.show(false)
+-----------------+
|predictions      |
+-----------------+
|0=0.5,1=0.3,2=0.2|
|0=0.6,1=0.2,2=0.2|
|0=0.1,1=0.1,2=0.8|
+-----------------+
```

Now, I also have metadata information about each of these indexes - `0,1,2...n` in a separate string. The metadata string looks like -

```
val metadata = "AA::BB::CC"
```

I would like to write a UDF in Scala to map these indexes to each element in the string. The output of that UDF should give me a new column which looks like this -

```
+--------------------+
|labelled_predictions|      
+--------------------+
|AA=0.5,BB=0.3,CC=0.2|
|AA=0.6,BB=0.2,CC=0.2|
|AA=0.1,BB=0.1,CC=0.8|
+--------------------+
```

So, `0` is replaced by `AA` since `AA` is the first element in the `metadata` string that is always split by `::`.

How do I write an UDF in Scala-Spark to do this ?

Comment: which Spark version are you using? a potential solution without UDF would work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val metadata = "AA::BB::CC"`

based on given data, this should work for you:

```
def myUDF(metadata:String) = udf((s: String) => {
  val metadataSplit = metadata.split("::")
  val dataSplit = s.split(",")
  val output = new Array[String](dataSplit.size)
  for (i <- 0 until dataSplit.size) {
    output(i) = metadataSplit(i) + "=" + dataSplit(i).split("=")(1)
  }
  output.mkString(",")
})
```

```
table1.withColumn("labelled_predictions", myUDF(metadata)(col("predictions"))).select("labelled_predictions").show(false)
```

output:

```
+--------------------+
|labelled_predictions|
+--------------------+
|AA=0.5,BB=0.3,CC=0.2|
|AA=0.6,BB=0.2,CC=0.2|
|AA=0.1,BB=0.1,CC=0.8|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: thanks , that works. I was creating a UDF to accept 2 params instead of 1. First param is the predictions string and second param is the metadata itself. How do i add the metadata as a param to the UDF using `lit()` function?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can use currying function to add params.